# get current window url with fbjs in iframe

Tags: facebook

I am facing with a problem when getting current window's url (facebook connect, iframe app). I could not get it with fbjs (strangely, there's a setLocation method to set url, but there's no method to get url), because facebook converts all javascript into fbjs. Did anybody has face with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to get the current page's location or any part of the url with fbjs.

Additionally fbjs is no longer recommended. You should now be building applications with iframe and new javascript sdk

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/